# Chrome - Window Width / Height Not Appearing in Developer Mode?

Tags: google-chrome

I just noticed that the window height / width are no longer appearing on the top right hand corner of the web page when I enter developer mode.

[image]

Not sure if I accidentally turned it off or if an version upgrade removed this functionality.

How do I turn this back on?  I am running version 49.0.2623.87.

Comment: Having the same issue and can't find a solution either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width and height at the top right hand corner of the window is gone.  To get a similar view, you now have to click on the device icon on the top left hand corner of the developer console (below in red).  Then on the screen that pops up, you need to select 'Responsive' on the device drop down tab on the top center of the screen (in blue).

[image]

Now you can see the width / height of the window and also resize it.

Answer (score 0):

I created a plugin to help me when I'm not using the responsive feature in Chrome's dev tools as it does not resize when using the dev tools to the side. Here's the link to the plugin: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/width-and-height-display/hhcddohiohbojnfdmfpbbhiaompeiemo?hl=en-US&gl=US

Alternatively, I took @Joefay and @Micah's (thanks!) answer from above and made a little visual in the upper right hand corner so you don't need to keep your console open after popping the code into the console. You will have to paste it in each time you open a new window or refresh your page however. Hope this helps.

```
var onresize = function() {
   var width = window.innerWidth
   || document.documentElement.clientWidth
   || document.body.clientWidth;
   var height = window.innerHeight
   || document.documentElement.clientHeight
   || document.body.clientHeight;
   var container = document.getElementById('heightAndWidth');
   container.innerHTML = width + ' x ' + height;
};

(function addHAndWElement() {
    var cssString = 'position:fixed;right:8px;top:8px;z-index:20000;background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);color:#FFF;padding:4px;'
    var htmlDoc = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    var divIdName = 'heightAndWidth';
    newDiv.setAttribute('id',divIdName);
    newDiv.style.cssText = cssString;
    htmlDoc[0].appendChild(newDiv);
    onresize();
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like after sufficient requests, the developer tools team [brought it back](https://twitter.com/ChromeDevTools/status/712675286110707717). In unstable/canary for now, soon in stable.